# How to get fetch all element of tree style array in PHP?

Tags: php

Here is a simple array. I want to fetch all pair of parent & child. How can I get?

```
$tree = array (
    1 => array (
            2 => "A",
            3 => "B",
            4 => array (
                    6 => "D",
                    7 => array (
                            8 => "E",
                            9 => array (
                                    10 => "F",
                                    11 => "G" 
                            ) 
                    ) 
            ),

            5 => "C" 
    )
```

);

Comment: Write a recursive function?!

Comment: @Rizier123 Can you explain me how to write recursive function?

Comment: Give expected output also

Comment: @Dan the out put I want is, key 1 value A, key 3 value B, key 4 value D,E,F,G and key 5 value C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer for pattern key 1 value A key 3 value B key 4 value D,E,F,G key 5 value C

```
$tree = array (
    1 => array (
            2 => "A",
            3 => "B",
            4 => array (
                    6 => "D",
                    7 => array (
                            8 => "E",
                            9 => array (
                                    10 => "F",
                                    11 => "G" 
                            ) 
                    ) 
            ),

            5 => "C" 
    )
);

// Loop through $tree array
// Since you are assigning array to index 1, 
// Use $tree[1] instead of just $tree
foreach($tree[1] as $key => $value)
{
    // Pring key
    echo "Key {$key}: ";

    // Check key value type is array or not
    if (gettype($value) == 'array')
    {
        // if it's array data type call recursive function
        print_array($value);
    } 
    else
    {
        // just pring value
        echo "{$value}, ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}

// Recursive function
// Takes array as parameter
function print_array(array $array)
{
    // Loop through associative array in the form of key and value
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        // If the value is array data type or not
        if (gettype($value) != 'array')
        {
            // if true, just print the value
            echo "$value";
        }
        else
        {
            // call recursive function
            print_array($value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use recursive function

```
$tree = array (
    1 => array (
            2 => "A",
            3 => "B",
            4 => array (
                    6 => "D",
                    7 => array (
                            8 => "E",
                            9 => array (
                                    10 => "F",
                                    11 => "G" 
                            ) 
                    ) 
            ),

            5 => "C" 
    )
);

// Recursive function
// Take array as parameter
function print_array(array $array)
{
    // Loop through associative array in the form of key and value
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        // If the value is array data type call recursive function 
        // by passing the value itself
        if (gettype($value) == 'array')
        {
            echo "New array of Key:{$key} started <br>";
            print_array($value);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the value is not array just print it
            echo "Key: {$key}, Value {$value} <br>";
        }
    }
}

print_array($tree);
```

Comment: I am not good at English so my explanation may be complicate. I want all parent and child value. example.. 
key 1 have 1 child
key 4 have 6 child 
So the out put I want is,
key 1 value A 
key 3 value B
key 4 value D,E,F,G
key 5 value C

Comment: @NyeinChan I have posted another answer in the pattern you had asked for.